# Translating Error Messages on Address Form

Tags: validation, form-validation, translate, js-translation

When only entering a few Required Fields when logged in and Adding a new address.

[image]

[image]

And then submitting that form, the error messages come back in English and not the translated format that is required.

CSV Translation files have been added along with relevant translations for these error messages